# How to disable indentation of LaTeX list items?

Tags: latex, margin

By default the "enumerate" environment is indented with respect to the current environment. How can I disable this indentation so that an enumerate environment of three items would produce the same output as the following piece of code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \paragraph{1.}
  \paragraph{2.}
  \paragraph{3.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled the three suggested methods into one file to be able to compare them side by side. Note that `\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}` does not have any effect on the `enumerate` environment. So far, the best solution is the `list` environment using the option `\leftmargin=1.4em`. However, I do not like a constant number in my code for it makes the code fragile. Does anyone know how to compute this constant (`1.4em`) in terms of available LaTeX variables?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section*{Paragraph}
\paragraph{1.} First
\paragraph{2.} Second
\paragraph{3.} Third

\section*{list}

\newcounter{itemcounter}
\begin{list}
{\textbf{\arabic{itemcounter}.}}
{\usecounter{itemcounter}\leftmargin=1.4em}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{list}

\section*{enumerate with leftmargin}
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi}.}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My test of the `\leftmargin` approach used the `newenvironemt` exhibited above, and did do the trick. I'm afraid You can do `\newlength{\enumindent}\setlength{\enumindent}{1.4em}` in the header to make it a named constant.

Answer (score 13):

Your best bet is probably to use either the [`mdwlist` package](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=mdwlist) or the [`enumlist` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/).

Or [this website](http://dikkie.net/2007/03/08/latex-indentation-itemize/) suggests the use of the `list` environment like this:

```
\begin{list}{\labelitemi}{\leftmargin=1em}
\item First item in the list
\item Second item
\item and so on
\end{list}
```

which suggests that you could redefine the length `leftmargin` in your enumeration if you prefer. Something like:

```
\newenvironment{flushenum}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}
```

which seems to work for me..

Answer (score 4):

This question appears to be dead, but in case somebody wanders across it as I did, there is also the `paralist` [package](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Inline_lists) which provides `asparaitem` and `asparaenum` environments, which do precisely this.

`paralist` also provides the `inparaenum` environment, which is designed for in-paragraph lists: something like "There are three ways to get there: one can (1) turn left, (2) turn right, or (3) go straight." You could use this environment and if you want you can insert your own paragraph breaks. This gives a flush enumerate but with indentation at the beginning of a paragraph. If it comes to that, maybe you should just use `\paragraph`.