# LaTex items left alignment in resume writing

Tags: alignment, latex, resume, tabular

I am trying to write a resume with LaTex. Does anyone know how to left flush items? The code I use is

```
    \documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage[letterpaper, margin=0.75in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mdwlist}
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\centering}

    \newcommand{\headerrow}[2]
       {\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
     #1 &
     #2 \\
        \end{tabular*}}

     \begin{document}
     \hrule
     \vspace{-0.4em}

     \subsection*{experience}
        \begin{itemize}
      \item[]
         \headerrow
          {\textbf{Teaching Inc.}}
          {\textbf{Chicago, IL}}
              \\
         \headerrow
          {\emph{Look and See}}
          {\emph{Vision}}
       \begin{itemize*}
     \item This is A
     \item This is B
       \end{itemize*}
        \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

And I get a results like
[image]
My question is, how can I left flush those items to align with the horizontal line. No indent and make them similar to the right flushed "Chicago, IL" and "vision". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left indent is created by your first `itemize` environment. Since you don't use the item symbols, you should remove it and everything would be flushed to the left.
With this code there is no left indent :

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\newcommand{\headerrow}[2]
{\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  #1 &
  #2 \\
\end{tabular*}}

\begin{document}
  \hrule
  \vspace{-0.4em}

  \subsection*{experience}
  \headerrow
  {\textbf{Teaching Inc.}}
  {\textbf{Chicago, IL}}
  \\
  \headerrow
  {\emph{Look and See}}
  {\emph{Vision}}
  \begin{itemize*}
    \item This is A
    \item This is B
  \end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

If you really want to keep the items, a lot of solutions are proposed here :  [How to disable indentation of LaTeX list items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427005/how-to-disable-indentation-of-latex-list-items)

NOTE : this question should be on https://tex.stackexchange.com/